# SQL Count days till first of the month

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

How would I count the days from a date till the first of the following month

Example:

```
--Start Date
07-07-2011
```

How many days till:

```
-- The 1st of the succeeding month of the start date above
08-01-2011
```

Expected Result (in days):

```
25
```

So if I counted the day I get 25, so running this query gets me the desired timestamp:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '25 DAYS'
```

Results:

```
2011-08-01 00:00:00
```

just can't think of a way to get the number of days, any suggestions?

Or start date, end date, number of days between?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a PostgreSQL server handy, so this is untested, but I would try:

```
SELECT (DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH') - CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Thanks, this does give me what I want

Comment: I did also find this works but I like yours better: SELECT ABS(CURRENT_DATE - '2011-08-01')