# SQL (Postgres): Time until next month

Tags: sql, postgresql

suppose I have a timestamp, how can I calculate the month's remaining time (in days/hours) ?

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate question, but you can find almost the exact answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612919/sql-count-days-till-first-of-the-month/6613019#6613019. The other question deals strictly in days.

Comment: @Tom H.: I think your comment should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
postgres=# select date_trunc('month', now() + interval '1 month') - now();
        ?column?         
-------------------------
 23 days 05:59:12.486972
(1 row)
```