# update table with dates with month

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

There's a table `dates_calendar`:

```
 id | date
 -------------------------
 13 | 2016-10-23 00:00:00
 14 | 2016-10-24 00:00:00
```

I need to update this table and insert dates until the next month counting from the last date in the table. E.g. last date is `2016-10-24 00:00:00` - I need to insert dates till `2016-10-31`. After that (the last date now is `2016-10-31`) next statement call should insert dates till `2016-11-30` and so on.

Example of my SQL code, but it inserts 30 days all the time.

```
INSERT INTO dates_calendar (date)
    VALUES (
      generate_series(
        (SELECT date FROM dates_calendar ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) + interval '1 day',
        (SELECT date FROM dates_calendar ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) + interval '1 month',
        '1 day'
      )
    );
```

I'm using PostgreSQL. As well would be fine to get rid of a duplicated SELECT statement of the last date.

Comment: this has been answered below, just to point out that an answer along the same lines already exists [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625707/sql-postgres-time-until-next-month)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into dates_calendar (date)
select dates::date
from (
    select max(date)::date+ 1 next_day, '1day'::interval one_day, '1month'::interval one_month
    from dates_calendar
    ) s,
    generate_series(
        next_day, 
        date_trunc('month', next_day)+ one_month- one_day, 
        one_day) dates;
```

Comment: Try it now, the column `date` casted to date.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the first and last date you need to insert you can use this query:

```
select max(date) + interval '1' day as first_day, 
       date_trunc('month', max(date) + interval '1' month) - interval '1' day as last_day
from dates_calendar
```

The expression `date_trunc('month', max(date) + interval '1' month)` calculates the start date of the *next* month. Subtracting one day from that will give you the last day of that month.

This can then be used to generate the list of dates:

```
with from_to (first_day, last_day) as (
  select max(date) + interval '1' day, 
         date_trunc('month', max(date) + interval '1' month) - interval '1' day
  from dates_calendar
)
select dt
from generate_series(  (select first_day from from_to), (select last_day from from_to), interval '1' day) as t(dt);
```

And finally this can be used to insert the generated rows into the table:

```
with from_to (first_day, last_day) as (
  select max(date) + interval '1' day, 
         date_trunc('month', max(date) + interval '1' month) - interval '1' day
  from dates_calendar
)
insert into dates_calendar (date)
select dt
from generate_series(  (select first_day from from_to), (select last_day from from_to), interval '1' day) as t(dt);
```

Comment: it works when `date_trunc('month', max(date)) + interval '1' month - interval '1' day` is changed to `date_trunc('month', max(date) + interval '1' day) + interval '1' month - interval '1' day`

Answer (score 0):

```
with max_date (d) as (select max(date)::date from dates_calendar)
insert into dates_calendar (date)
select d
from generate_series (
    (select d from max_date) + 1,
    (select date_trunc('month', d + interval '1 month')::date - 1 from max_date),
    '1 day'
) g(d)
```

Comment: it works when `select date_trunc('month', d + interval '1 month')::date - 1 from max_date` is changed to `select date_trunc('month', d + interval '1 day' + interval '1 month')::date - 1 from max_date`